# How to navigate using BottomNavigation without tapping the navbar

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a question regarding navigation if you're using the NativeScript Vue Tab Navigation. I am using the NativeScript Vue Tab Navigation Template (https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/tns-template-tab-navigation-vue) provided by the Nativescript Team and trying to navigate from the Browse component to Items component with a simple button within the Browse component. So I would like to be able to navigate to another component without clicking on one of the tabs provided in the template. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Cheers!

```
App.vue:
<template lang="html">
    <BottomNavigation>
        <TabStrip>
            <TabStripItem class="navigation__item">
                <Label text="Home"></Label>
                <Image src.decode="font://&#xf015;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
            </TabStripItem>
            <TabStripItem class="navigation__item">
                <Label text="Browse"></Label>
                <Image src.decode="font://&#xf1ea;" class="far t-36"></Image>
            </TabStripItem>
            <TabStripItem class="navigation__item">
                <Label text="History"></Label>
                <Image src.decode="font://&#xf002;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
            </TabStripItem>
        </TabStrip>
        <TabContentItem>
            <Frame id="items">
                <Items/>
            </Frame>
        </TabContentItem>
        <TabContentItem>
            <Frame id="browse">
                <Browse/>
            </Frame>
        </TabContentItem>
        <TabContentItem>
            <Frame id="search">
                <History/>
            </Frame>
        </TabContentItem>
    </BottomNavigation>
</template>
<script>
    import Items from "./Items.vue";
    import Browse from "./Browse.vue";
    import History from "./History.vue";
    export default {
        components: {
            Items,
            Browse,
            History
        }
    };
</script>
<style lang="scss">
    // Start custom common variables
    @import "~@nativescript/theme/scss/variables/blue";
    // End custom common variables
    // Custom styles
</style>
```

```
Browse component:
<template lang="html">
    <Page>
        <ActionBar>
            <Label text="Browse"></Label>
        </ActionBar>
        <GridLayout class="page__content">
            <Label class="page__content-icon far" text.decode="&#xf1ea;"></Label>
            <Button @tap="navigate" >navigate to Items</Button>
            <Label class="page__content-placeholder" :text="message"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
<script>
    import Items from "./Items";
  export default {
      components: {
          Items
      },
    data() {
      return {
        message: "<!-- Browse page content goes here -->"
      };
    },
      methods: {
          navigate() {
              this.$navigateTo(Items);
          }
      }
  }
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    // Start custom common variables
    @import "~@nativescript/theme/scss/variables/blue";
    // End custom common variables
    // Custom styles
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `selectedIndex` property of `BottomNavigation` to set which tab should be selected when you click on the button.

```html
<BottomNavigation :selectedIndex="selectedIndex">
```